# How to display common era ("CE") in Java-8?

Tags: java, java-8, java-time

Following code does not print "CE" or "Current Era":

```
System.out.println(IsoEra.CE.getDisplayName(TextStyle.SHORT, Locale.UK)); // output: AD
System.out.println(IsoEra.CE.getDisplayName(TextStyle.FULL, Locale.UK)); // output: Anno Domini
```

Of course, `IsoEra.CE.name()` helps but not if the full display name like "common era" or "current era" is required. I consider this a little bit strange because the javadoc of `IsoEra` explicitly mentions the term "Current era" in its class description. It does not even work for root locale. The use-case here is to serve clients with a non-religious background.

This does not help, too:

```
LocalDate date = LocalDate.now();
String year = date.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("G yyyy", Locale.UK)); // AD 2015
System.out.println(year);
```

The only way I found was:

```
TextStyle style = ...;
Map<Long,String> eras = new HashMap<>();
long bce = (long) IsoEra.BCE.getValue(); // 0L
long ce = (long) IsoEra.CE.getValue(); // 1L
if (style == TextStyle.FULL) {
  eras.put(bce, "Before current era");
  eras.put(ce, "Current era");
} else {
  eras.put(bce, "BCE");
  eras.put(ce, "CE");
}
DateTimeFormatter dtf = 
  new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
  .appendText(ChronoField.ERA, eras)
  .appendPattern(" yyyy").toFormatter();
System.out.println(LocalDate.now().format(dtf)); // CE 2015
```

Is there any better or shorter way?

Comment: Use a locale that uses the "politically correct" variant, because AD and anno domini **are** the correct texts for CE in most western locales.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Which locale do you suggest? With an extra variant part and installing associated resources via ServiceLoader?

Comment: If only one could find suche a Locale! Even the supposedly language and country neutral Locale.ROOT throws "AD" at you like it were going out of style (which I'd applaud).

Comment: looks like in the current implementation only Malay (ms) and Indonesian (in, id) are "politically correct" or "secular" - even Hebrew uses BC/AD

Comment: e.g. `IsoEra.CE.getDisplayName(TextStyle.SHORT, new Locale("ms"))` -> CE

Comment: @harshtuna this shouild be an answer, not a comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no better way to do it!

Explanation: "Current era" (and accoridngly "before current era") is the "name of a field"(abstract/meta) of the ISO standard. Of course there is also **no** (standardized) country specific translation for these fields and no pattern which prints this output.(By the standard they are referenced in english only, and by jdk respectively only as `CE, BCE`). So what the original output shows:

```
  AD
  Anno Domini
```

is correct, and the ISO-conform (english) translation of the era (of a date which is "in  the current era").

To solve this, I absolutely agree with your approach (of custom date formatting), and going deeper into details: I wouldn't dare to change a single line of it!

The only savings potential I see is in "initialization"(maybe use a EnumMap for the TextStyles...and ... how many languages do you want to support?) ..and "by refactoring".

Thank you for the interesting "problem", and providing a solution to it!

Comment: About ISO, this paper is silent about eras, so better leave it out in this context (but year zero! exists). You are probably right, no really better solution possible. I discovered that for `SimpleDateFormat` in Java pre 8 the situation is even worse (no long era names). I wish Oracle had a heart for people who need alternatives. In English the names "common era" etc. aren't unusual, and in East Germany there are also names like "v.u.Z." instead of "v.Chr.". I think I will go with a ServiceLoader-mechanism and manage my own text resources accessible via a locale-variant. Thanks.